# как правильно построить отношение в таблице

Tags: база-данных, модель-данных

> Лодочная станция дает в аренду катера, байдарки водные лыжи и прочее.
>   Их можно использовать в трех водоемах реке озере или пруду. Нужно
>   указать опасность плавания для каждого типа плавсредства.

То есть я имею три таблицы: `ПЛАВСРВА(id, тип, название)`, `ВОДОЕМЫ(id, тип)`, `ОПАСНОСТЬ(id, тип)`.

В кратце должно звучать или выглядеть, даже не знаю как описать ЕСЛИ тип плавср-ва ЯХТА и водоем ПРУД то опасность ВЫСОКАЯ.

Comment: не пойму как сделать связь один-ко-многим, и какие дополнительные таблицы можно создать

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE CurAttraction (
      CurAttraction_ID int NOT NULL
    , Watercraft_ID int
    , Pond_ID int
    , Risk_ID int
    , PRIMARY KEY (CurAttraction_ID)
    , FOREIGN KEY (Watercraft_ID) REFERENCES Watercraft(Watercraft_ID)
    , FOREIGN KEY (Pond_ID) REFERENCES Pond(Pond_ID)
    , FOREIGN KEY (Risk_ID) REFERENCES Risk(Risk_ID)
)
```

Comment: спасибо за код конечно)) но я еще на уровне ER-диаграмм так что мне это еще не совсем понятно

Comment: @Zakat, вам надо просто создать ОДНУ таблицу, которая будет связывать ваши справочники.